# Am I supposed to pass around Pino child loggers?

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda

This is rather a stylistic question. I'm using Pino in some of my Javascript/Typescript microservices. As they're running on AWS I'd like to propagate the RequestId.

When one of my functions is invoked, I'm creating a new child logger like this:

```
const parentLogger = pino(pinoDefaultConfig)

function createLogger(context) {
  return parentLogger.child({
    ...context,
  })
}

function createLoggerForAwsLambda(awsContext) {
  const context = {
    requestId: awsContext.awsRequestId,
  }
  return createLogger(context)
}
```

I'm then passing down the logger instance to all methods. That said, `(... , logger)` is in almost every method signature which is not too nice. Moreover, I need to provide a logger in my tests.

How do you do it? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

you should implement some sort of Dependency Injection and include your logger there.
if your using microservices and maybe write lambdas in a functional approach, you can handle it by separating the initialization responsibility in a fashion like this:

```
import { SomeAwsEvent } from 'aws-lambda';
import pino from 'pino';

const createLogger = (event: SomeAwsEvent) => {
  return pino().child({
    requestId: event.requestContext.requestId
  })
}

const SomeUtil = (logger: pinno.Logger) => () => {
  logger.info('SomeUtil: said "hi"');
}

const init(event: SomeAwsEvent) => {
  const logger = createLogger(event);
  someUtil = SomeUtil(logger);
  
  return {
    logger,
    someUtil
  }
}

export const handler = (event: SomeAwsEvent) => {
  const { someUtil } = init(event);

  someUtil();

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use some DI library helper to tackle this

```js
import { createContainer } from "iti"
interface Logger {
  info: (msg: string) => void
}
class ConsoleLogger implements Logger {
  info(msg: string): void {
    console.log("[Console]:", msg)
  }
}
class PinoLogger implements Logger {
  info(msg: string): void {
    console.log("[Pino]:", msg)
  }
}

interface UserData {
  name: string
}

class AuthService {
  async getUserData(): Promise<UserData> {
    return { name: "Big Lebowski" }
  }
}

class User {
  constructor(private data: UserData) {}
  name = () => this.data.name
}

class PaymentService {
  constructor(private readonly logger: Logger, private readonly user: User) {}
  sendMoney() {
    this.logger.info(`Sending monery to the: ${this.user.name()} `)
    return true
  }
}

export async function runMyApp() {
  const root = createContainer()
    .add({
      logger: () =>
        process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
          ? new PinoLogger()
          : new ConsoleLogger(),
    })
    .add({ auth: new AuthService() })
    .add((ctx) => ({
      user: async () => new User(await ctx.auth.getUserData()),
    }))
    .add((ctx) => ({
      paymentService: async () =>
        new PaymentService(ctx.logger, await ctx.user),
    }))

  const ps = await root.items.paymentService
  ps.sendMoney()
}

console.log(" ---- My App START \n\n")
runMyApp().then(() => {
  console.log("\n\n ---- My App END")
})
```

it is easy to write tests too:

```
import { instance, mock, reset, resetCalls, verify, when } from "ts-mockito"
import { PaymentService } from "./payment-service"
import type { Logger } from "./logger"

const mockedLogger = mock<Logger>()
when(mockedLogger.info).thenReturn(() => null)

describe("Payment service: ", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    resetCalls(mockedLogger)
    // reset(mockedLogger)
  })
  it("should call logger info when sending money", () => {
    const paymentService = new PaymentService(instance(mockedLogger))
    expect(paymentService.sendMoney()).toBe(true)
  })
})
```

Answer (score -1):

I would not use the requestId as part of the context of the logger, but use it as the payload of the logger, like `logger.info({ requestId }, myLogMessage)`. This was you can have a simple function create a child logger that you can use for the entire module.